# startsWith method not supported in IE any replacement for this?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
var s = "Main String";
s.startsWith("Main");
```

Replacing startWith with a similar logic or any other method generic to all browsers.

Comment: The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) contains a polyfill.

Comment: Normally, you should’ve Googled _before_ asking a question here.

Comment: Yeah, you really should have googled this first.

Answer (score 16):

A good replacement for `startsWith` would be using `s.substring(0, 4) == 'Main'`

This should work, so go ahead and try it.

Comment: Its very hard coded.

Answer (score 4):

Add a prototype method in String:

```
String.prototype.myStartsWith = function(str){
 if(this.indexOf(str)===0){
  return true;
 }else{
   return  false;
 }
};
```

Now call:

```
s.myStartsWith("Main");
```

Comment: Is the reason against doing this that it's not as efficient as the other solution?

Comment: Remenber to check if exist before overwrite:

`if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
    String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position){
      return this.substr(position || 0, searchString.length) === searchString;
  };
}`